# Alterar o Valor do json com PHP

Tags: php, json

Tenho um arquivo json onde eu estou listando as informações que me interessam com PHP.

Estou usando o Lottie.js para rodar este .json como um gif/vídeo, a minha ideia é alterar as mensagens em inglês para português, estou conseguindo listar elas do json, mas não sei como altera, segue meu código:

```
<?php
$url = 'js/data3.json';

$jsonStr = file_get_contents($url);
$jsonArr = json_decode($jsonStr, true);


$titulo = array();


foreach ($jsonArr['layers'] as $row) {

$titulo[] = $row['nm'];


 }
?>
```

o resultado que eu estou tendo é:

```
Keep an eye out for an email 
Message sent
Send Message
```

<sup>(está trazendo os textos)</sup>

Como eu Altero o Valor `Message sent` por `Mensagem enviada` por exemplo?

**Link do Json:** https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=e231e4df96f349f281002c689d84ab0f

Comment: Seria interessante se tivessemos um exemplo do json

Comment: vou postar aqui, ta?

Comment: é só editar a pergunta e jogar o json lá

Comment: feito, joguei no final do post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minha primeira interação com JSON com o PHP, já tinha feito algo um pouco mais complexo com XML, mas a ideia é a mesma, as funções que mudam:

Salvei o json em um arquivo `.JSON` na mesma pasta do arquivo PHP.

```
<?php
//abrindo o json externo
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('teste.json'));

//Editando a linha que vc quer
$json->layers[1]->nm = "Mensagem Enviada";

//Salvando as edições
$json_editado = file_put_contents('teste.json',json_encode($json));

//Carregando json após ser salvo já editado
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('teste.json'));
//Imprimindo json editado
var_dump($json);
?>
```

O que pode atrapalhar um pouco é que parte do json tem Array, e pode atrapalhar um pouco na hora de chegar no atributo ou no objeto.

Comment: sabe o que é pior, eu alterei as Mensagens e está em Português, mas a renderização do lottie continua trazendo em inglês

Comment: Consegui! Obrigado!!!!